# How do I break up my numbers into multiple lines?

Tags: java, break

Run the program with starting number=13, upper bound= 112, step_size=3 
Continue printing numbers as long as number

I've tried to split it and use break without success for this task.

```
public class Bounds {  
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int startingNumber;
        int upperBound = 112;
        int stepSize =3;
        int count =0;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter starting number: ");
        startingNumber=input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter upper bound number");
        upperBound = input.nextInt();

        System.out.print(startingNumber + " ");

        System.out.print(" ");

        while (startingNumber <= upperBound) {

            System.out.print((startingNumber += stepSize) + " ");

            if ((count%10) == 0)
                count += 3;

            System.out.print( " ");

            input.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see a `break` statement -- but please note that this tag does not refer to line breaks.  You might want to add the "java" tag.  Also, you seem to be missing a few lines -- I don't see closing curly braces for the `while` loop, the `main` method, or the class.

Comment: looking for System.out.println , will give you line brak

Comment: What are you expecting `if ((count%10) == 0) count += 3;` to do?

Comment: General tip: `input.close()` should get called only once, so don't put it in the loop. Keep it either before or after the loop.

Comment: "Continue printing numbers as long as number ..." it would help us if we knew what the stop condition was.

Answer (score 0):

too complicated, what about using a for loop

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int startingNumber;
    int upperBound = 112;
    int stepSize =3;
    int count =0;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter starting number: ");
    startingNumber = input.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter upper bound number");
    upperBound = input.nextInt();

    int range = upperBound - startingNumber;
    for (int i = startingNumber; i < upperBound; i+=stepSize) {
        System.out.println(i);
        count++;
                }
    System.out.println("done: count value: "+count);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What did you have in mind for the following?

```java
         if ((count%10) == 0)
                count += 3;
```

So you only increment count when the remainder is zero.  That would only work once.  But what other action do you take?  Perhaps you meant do do something like this.

```java
         count += 3;
         if ((count%10 == 0) {
               System.out.println();
         }
```